# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 error after deploying project

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer, body-parser

I built a NodeJS/Angular project for a buddy of mine. Everything works fine locally, but once I made the project live, I got an error. The website is chestnutdetailing.com, and if you try to set an appointment you can duplicate the error i'm getting. I believe the error is with my server.js or app.js file. I'm using Express. When it tries to POST to /contact, I get a 404 error, pictured below. [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5sOg.png).

Here is my server.js code

```js
console.log("made it in the server file");

var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json({}));

app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log("Listening on port 8080.....")
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
     host: 'db694694191.db.1and1.com',
     port:3306,
     user: '.....',
     password: '.....',
     database: 'db694694191'
   });
   connection.connect();


app.post('/contact', function(req, res, next){
    //console.log(req.body);
    var appointment = req.body;
    
    
      var query = connection.query('insert into appointments set ?', appointment, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return res.send(err);
        } else {
          return res.send('Ok');
          }

          
})});

app.get('/contact', function(req, res){
  var query = connection.query('select * from appointments order by id desc limit 1;',function(err,rows){
    if(err) {
      consol.error(err);
      return res.send(err);
    } else {

        console.log();
        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
                user: '...',
                pass: '.....'
            }
        });

        var mailOptions = {
            from: '...',
            
            to: '...',
            subject: 'Detailing Appointment Request - ' + rows[0].name,
            html: '<p><i>You have a new detailing appointment request. Please respond to this customer within 24 hours. </i></p><h2>Customer Information</h2><p><b>Name</b>: ' + rows[0].name + '</p> <p><b>Phone</b>: ' + rows[0].number + '</p> <p><b>Email</b>: ' + rows[0].email + '</p> <h2>Order Information</h2> <p><b>Request ID</b>: ' + rows[0].id + '</p> <p><b>Date/Time</b>: ' + rows[0].date + ' at ' + rows[0].time + '</p> <p><b>Service</b>: 1 ' + rows[0].vehicle_type + ', ' + rows[0].service + '</p> <p><b>Additional Services</b>: ' + rows[0].add_on + '</p>'
        };

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
            }
        });
      return res.send(rows);
    }
})});
```

and here is the relevant portion of my app.js file:

```js
//Database connection
    $scope.submit= function(){
      console.log('clicked submit');
      var appointment = {
          name: $scope.name,
          number : $scope.number,
          email : $scope.email,
          vehicle_type: $scope.generateModel.vehicleType,
          service: $scope.generateModel.service,
          add_on: $scope.generateModel.addOnService,
          date: $scope.moment($scope.dt).format('MM/DD/YYYY'),
          time: $scope.moment($scope.mytime).format('hh:mm A'),
      }

      $http({
        url: 'http://chestnutdetailing.com/contact',
        method: 'POST',
        data: appointment
      }).then(function() {
        $scope.getAppointments();
      })
   };

   $scope.getAppointments = function() {
     $http({
       url: 'http://chestnutdetailing.com/contact',
       method: 'GET'
     }).then(function(response) {
       $scope.lastAppointment = response;
       $scope.openAppointmentModal($scope.lastAppointment);
     })
   }
```

Comment: Is express still listening on port 8080?

Comment: You absolutely sure it's a good idea to have a public repo with your db creds in plain text? And your email password?

Comment: @Randy Casburn yes!

Comment: @mingos it's been deleted. I included a link to the wrong repo. thank you

Comment: So express is listening on 8080, and you expect this url:http://chestnutdetailing.com/contact to respond?

Comment: @Randy Casburn first time working with it, does it need to be listening to the url?

Comment: HTTP's default port is port 80, so when you use any URL like this: `http://somedomain.com/contact` it is exactly the same as using `http://somedomain.com:80/contact`. But, when you modify the port your server is listening on, in this case you have your server listening on port 8080. So if that is your **deployed server code**, you URLs must be: `http://somedomain.com:8080/contact` - alternatively, you could change the port back to the default (which I recommend).

Comment: I just checked, and `http://chestnutdetailing.com/contact` is not at 8080, so you must be using different server code than what is here.

Comment: @RandyCasburn when i was building locally, I would have to use the command "node server.js" to initiate the server file for it to work properly. I think thats part of my issue now

Comment: How did you deploy your nodeJS/Express code to the server?

Comment: SFTP, uploaded the files to my webspace directory. @RandyCasburn

Comment: Right - just checked - you are not serving from nodeJS/express on your server, you are serving from Apache (and most likely from a shared hosting service - meaning the server side code is meant to be PHP - not nodejs). **None of your NodeJS code is even in effect in your deployed environment**

Comment: @RandyCasburn So I would need to find a root server that works with NodeJS, I assume.

Comment: Yes - go here and follow this tutorial. After the tutorial you can substitute your own code and make it work with nodeJS. http://labs.roitraining.com/labs/gcp-node-express-cloud-functions/index.html#0

Comment: Thanks a ton! This is my first web app, so all the help is appreciated! @RandyCasburn

Comment: glad to help...there is a lot more to do :-)

Comment: how about some cred - I'll put up an answer that summarizes this and you accept it?

Comment: @RandyCasburn no problem. This helps a ton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You web app is currently deployed on shared host using the Apache web server. Your NodeJS/Express server code is not being used. For this to work the way you expect, you'll need to deploy to a service that will execute you NodeJS code. I recommend you go through this tutorial to publish your app to Google's Cloud.

http://labs.roitraining.com/labs/gcp-node-express-cloud-functions/index.html#0